# ASP.NET MVC : how to get article's url from search result?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC project. I'm trying to get article urls from view after searching. I don't know how to get it in controller.

Thanks for any ideas.

Here is my part of view:

```
<table>
     @foreach (var item in Model)
     {
            <tr>
                <td>
                   <a href="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.url)" target="_blank"> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.title)</a>
                </td>
                <td>
                   @Html.DisplayFor(GetNews1s => item.author)
                </td>
                <td>
                   @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.publishedAt)
                </td>
           </tr>
     }
</table>
```

And here is my part of controller:

```
var userList = from s in db.GetNews1s() select s;

if (searchString != null)
{
    userList = userList.Where(s => s.title.Contains(searchString)
                                || s.author.Contains(searchString));

    string sd = startdate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
    string ed = enddate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

    run_cmd("D:/Python/wordcloudjieba.py", "" + sd + "", "" + ed + "");

    ViewBag.wc = @"picture/wcp1.png";     
}

if (startdate.HasValue)
{
     userList = userList.Where(x => x.publishedAt > startdate.Value.Date);
     ViewBag.startdate = startdate;                
}

if (enddate.HasValue)
{
     userList = userList.Where(x => x.publishedAt < enddate.Value.Date);
     ViewBag.enddate = enddate;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Answer (score 0):

If you have "@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.url)",  then it won't post value back to controller. Add this as below.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.url)
```

Comment: Hi,thanks for answer.But I still don't know how to post url back to controller after i add `@Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.url)`